# Help a newbie. Need software

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, mining-theory, development, mining-hardware

I want to invest in a mining farm. Everywhere I find only pieces of information. Help please - you need: What software is needed and for what. Where to begin. Equipment and installation conditions.

---

Let's say I have a room, electricity and racks. Collected several rigs. How do I start them? What software do you need?

Comment: What do you want to mine with?

Comment: I do not know. I want to figure out what will be more profitable. On the one hand, there are ASICs, they are convenient and already configured.
 But dear ones. video cards are more variable and cheaper. But there is a lot of trouble with them (((

Comment: his is a very big job. We must start with the formation and the budgetary part depending on what equipment you use. Are you going to use video cards? what?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=start+mining

Answer (score 1):

If you have no money, you might just install virtualbox and put a Linux node on it to download bitcoin core (details for installing this free software are in Antonopoulos' book "Mastering Bitcoin").  But this will not be fast enough to actually mine bitcoin (well it will dig but unlikely to win any blocks at the current difficulty level)--you could have a full node for fun though.

If you are more serious, you might start by buying an Antminer--here's a youtube video by a funny person hooking one up:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz-XZL77qqs (it's an Antminer S9 from 2017).  Once you do this you'll have an idea how power, heat, and space will impact your farm.  And you could join a pool to get some reward at least:)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

start with a training video, usually on websites along with programs, there are instructions and training videos

for example
One of the most popular and effective mining programs is –  [Awesome Miner](https://bittention.com/software/download-awesome-miner-how-to-set-up-awesome-miner/), [GUI Miner](https://bittention.com/software/download-free-gui-miner-for-mine-bitcoin/),
Video Cards AMD – [OverdriveNTool](https://bittention.com/software/download-overdriventool-0-2-9-updated-to-the-latest-version/)
Nvidia rtx3060 – [470.05 Beta driver](https://bittention.com/software/beta-driver-470-05-download-for-rtx-3060/), [472.12](https://bittention.com/software/download-game-ready-driver-472-12-for-rtx-30-series/)
Bios  - [RED BIOS EDITOR](https://bittention.com/software/download-red-bios-editor-for-windows/), [NiBiTor](https://bittention.com/software/download-nvidia-bios-editor-nibitor/), [Phoenix Bios Editor 2.2.1.3](https://bittention.com/software/download-phoenix-bios-editor-usage-of-version-2-2-1-3/)